# How to have standard Windows dotted selection in QTableView?

Tags: windows, qt, selection

QTableView has a lot of selection modes, but all of them result in a kind of selection where clicking anywhere on the row selects the whole row, and no selection rectangle is shown.

When I select items, I want to have the standard selection rectangle with dotted borders. The items also should be selected only when I actually hover over the item's text.

In other words I want it to behave like desktop selection.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to select a single item:

```
tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectItems);
```

And this will help you to get dotted borders:

```
tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that when you `setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection)` on your view, you still get the behavior of clicking selecting the entire row? That shouldn't be the case.

What is your model's class -- if derived, what Qt model do you derive from and what is your implementation of `flags()`?